# Retrieve or Query Pages by ID

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, query

I have a problem with my code, I want to display 3 specific pages on my homepage but my code is not working.. here's the code..

```
<?php $args = array(
                      'post_type' => 'page',
                      'post__in' => array(3,5,7)
                      );
                    query_posts($args);
                    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                    $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>
                <div class ="date_author group">
                    <h3 class="date"><?php the_time('M j, y');?></h3>
                    </div>
                    <h3 class="title"><a STYLE="text-decoration:none" href = "<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php           the_title();?></a></h3>

                    <?php the_excerpt();?>

                    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: _Not working_ is not a useful description. What happens instead? What [debug data](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) did you collect? Read [How to ask a good question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm sorry, The code displays nothing.. I'm sure that I have pages ID 3, 5, and 7 but it displays nothing.

Comment: Use `get_posts()` and enable the debug mode.

Comment: Thank you, you give me another idea on retrieving a post,, Im just a newbie in wordpress and it really helps but..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an inappropriate use of `query_posts()` which is only for modifying the *main query* for the page. Additionally, even if you change your snippet to use `get_posts()`, your template tags (e.g. `the_excerpt()`) won't work as `get_posts()` isn't a method of looping through posts, it just returns an array of posts.

What you want is [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). Change your first lines of code to this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post__in' => array(3,5,7)
);
$my_three_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
while ($my_three_posts -> have_posts()) : $my_three_posts -> the_post();
...
```